# PDO do not able to fetch huge data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to fetch data from one mysql table with more than 5 M rows and 50 Gb total size, I use PDO for it. It looks like

```
$urlsContent = $db->query('select url_hash,content from sy_search_site_stat');
while($result = $urlsContent->fetch())
{
    ... write content to files;
    ... echo content hashes;
}
```

But when I run it without limit in console, the only output is 
    "Killed" after several minutes of working. When I write limit to SQL query, it works fine. Are there any particular restrictions on PDO?

Comment: `set_time_limit(0)` should help.

Comment: For your usecase use the `SELECT ... INTO` syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html

Comment: Do you have an index on the `sy_search_site_stat` column? If not, it sounds like you need one, with the table size you have. There is no particular restriction in PDO on table/database size, no.

Comment: Investigate more and search for error message.

Comment: May be - you have to change some Apache/MySql servers timeouts..

Comment: No, unfortunately set_time_limit is already 0 in ini settings
Also, I need to write each row in its separate file (of cause in different dirs)
I don't understand, how index can help me cause I have to fetch all rows.
I think I can do everything by making a lot of queries with %100=n condition, but I want to understand, why it can't be fetched with one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
```

[source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.html)